# Issues using Google Analytics with Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, google-analytics

I'm attempting to using Google Analytics to log events in Angular. been following their instructions but I'm running into issues.

The initial calls off that the GA library makes for page view and user engagement work fine, so I know I'm initializing the library fine, but the subsequent gtag calls I make never get logged.

Weirder still, if I use the dev console while my page is being served, I can log events just fine, so it seems like an issue specifically calling it in Angular. Anyone have any insights?

I've put a code example here for anyone. It's using SkyUX, so you'll have to do some setup to get it running here:
https://developer.blackbaud.com/skyux/learn/get-started

Thanks all!
https://github.com/JosephZelada/google-analytics-example